# PHP Get current url change query string and redirect

Tags: php, pagination, paging

I would like to get the current url, change the paged parameter if exists and reload the page again with the parameter updated..

I'm getting the page URL like this: `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but after this, I dont know what to do

Comment: what the hell? whyt he hell you answred my question then? whata  great desrespect

Answer (score 4):

```
$_GET['page'] = 1;
echo strtok($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'?').'?'.http_build_query($_GET);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps:

1. Parse the url using func. [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)
2. Change your parameter.
3. Build url again using func. : '[http_build_url](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)'
4. Redirect to new generated url.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect user to some address, you must set `Location` header using [header()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php) function. See manual for examples. The address you may form according to `$_GET` array or somewhat else.